# semantics of end() iterator for vector and list

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

According to the C++ standard, calling `push_back()` on a vector invalidates the iterator if the new size of the vector grows above its capacity, but on a list it never invalidates iterators. Now consider the following code snippets:

1.

```
vector<int> v{1,2,3};
v.reserve(100);
for (int i: v) {
    v.push_back(i);
}
```

2.

```
list<int> l{1,2,3};
for (int i: l) {
    l.push_back(i);
}
```

I tried it with gcc 4.8 and found that code 1 finishes with `v` being `{1,2,3,1,2,3}`, but code 2 runs into an infinite loop. The explanation seems pretty simple to me: the `end()` iterator of `vector` points to a memory location, and since [it is only evaluated once during a range based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), it stops when it reaches past the 3rd element of the vector. On the other hand, `list` probably has some kind of null token as an end iterator, which is always placed after the last element, thus the loop will never reach it.

While the results seem straightforward, my question is what does the standard say about this? Is it supposed to be so in every standard library implementations, or is this behavior not defined? What should I expect when writing a loop that may call `push_back()` to such a container (which I usually like to avoid anyway)?

Comment: I guess the Standard does not have much to say about this. It is allowed, it is legal, it is just an infinite loop

Comment: @AndyProwl I think the standard does have something to say: it is required to be an endless loop.  (If it isn't an endless loop with `vector`, it is because there is undefined behavior, so anything the implementation does is legal.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, that's the same I meant to say. The OP wrote a legal infinite loop, there's nothing the standard has to say about that particular situation (talking about the list example of course).

Comment: For reference, `§23.3.6.5/1`: "*Remarks:* Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity. If no reallocation happens,
all the iterators and references **before the insertion point** remain valid."

Comment: @Xeo thanks, that's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that the standard is very explicit, but in
general, `end` means `end`, and if you insert elements beyond
the current position in a loop, you'll never get there.

Of course, your first loop, with `vector`, has undefined
behavior, since insert (and erase) invalidates all iterators at
or beyond the position of the insertion, even if there is no
reallocation.  And the end iterator will always be beyond the
point of insertion.

Comment: According to cppreference.com, iterators in `vector` are only invalidated if the size grouws through capacity. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back
Does this reflect the standard correctly, or does it say that they can be invalidated at any call to `push_back`?

Comment: @petersohn: Cppreference literally says "...Otherwise no iterators and references are invalidated." This is patently wrong. From the purely "physical" point of view one can understand their logic, but the language spec takes a more high-level approach. All iterators and references that refer to "shifted" elements are considered invalidated, even though they might still refer to valid memory locations.

Comment: @petersohn According the the standard (§23.3.6.5): "[...] If no
reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before
the insertion point remain valid."  (If they aren't guaranteed
to remain valid, they are invalid.  This is a blatant error at
the site you quote.

Comment: @AndreyT All iterators which no longer point to the element they previously pointed to are considered invalid.  (It's highly likely that in `std::vector`, an iterator after the insertion will point to the element in front of the one it previously pointed to if no allocation occurs, but the standard doesn't try to standardize such "accidental" behavior.)

Comment: @James Kanze: Um... That's exactly what I'm saying in my comment above.

Comment: @nateKohl there is an iterator located after the location where `push_back` places its element -- the one-past-the-end iterator, aka `end()`.

Comment: @Yakk: right, I figured that out right before you answered. :)

Comment: @AndreyT and @James Kanze: the cppreference docs for `std::vector::push_back` should be better now.